# Using Kubernetes or Apache mesos

Tags: apache, hadoop, docker, kubernetes, mesos

We have a product which is described in some docker files, which can create the necessary docker containers. Some docker containers will just run some basic apps, while other containers will run clusters (hadoop).

Now is the question which cluster manager I need to use.
Kubernetes or Apache mesos or both?

I read Kubernetes is good for 100% containerized environments, while Apache Mesos is better for environments which are a bit containerized and a bit not-containerized. But Apache Mesos is better for running hadoop in docker (?).

Our environment is composed of only docker containers, but some with an hadoop cluster and some with some apps.

What will be the best?

Comment: Mesos can support container itself: [http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/docker-containerizer/](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/docker-containerizer/). Isn't is enough?

Comment: similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611897/scaling-docker-containers-in-the-real-world/34621475#34621475

Answer (score 4):

Both functionally do the same, orchestrate Docker containers, but obviously they will do it in different ways and what you can easily achieve with one, it might prove difficult in the other and vice versa.
Mesos has a higher complexity and learning curve in my opinion. Kubernetes is relatively simpler and easier to grasp. You can literally spawn your own Kube master and minions running one command and specifying the provider: Vagrant or AWS,etc. Kubernetes is also able to be integrated into Mesos, so there is also the possibility where you could try both.
For the Hadoop specific use case you mention, Mesos might have an edge, it might integrate better in the Apache ecosystem, Mesos and Spark were created by the same minds.
Final thoughts: start with Kube, progressively exploring how to make it work for your use case. Then, after you have a good grasp on it, do the same with Mesos. You might end up liking pieces of each and you can have them coexist, or find that Kube is enough for what you need.